# Change the Default Purchase Order view form OpenERP

Tags: forms, view, odoo

I have created a new view for Purchase order form. I want to apply this view when we create a purchase order. However, I did not find any option to replace the default Purchase order form view. I tried with actions. It didn't work.

First on clicking the Purchase Orders, it should display the list of Purchase Orders. Then when we move to create purchase order, it should redirect to the new form which I have created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is a field called "priority" on model "ir.ui.view" and default it is set to 16. if you made a complete new form view for purchase.order, just set this field to a lower value. the actions on the purchases menus for purchase.order aren't set to any special view, so the view with the lowest priority will be chosen automatically.

edit: if you want to have a menu wichh opens a form view of purchase order with your defined form view, you have to use it in an action, like:

```
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="your_form_view_id">
... your form view ...
</record>

<record id="your_action_id" model="ir.actions.act_window">
    <field name="name">Menu Name</field>
    <field name="type">ir.actions.act_window</field>
    <field name="res_model">purchase.order</field>
    <field name="view_type">form</field>
    <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
    <field name="view_id" ref="your_form_view_id" />
</record>

<menuitem action="your_action_id" id="your_menu_id" parent="your_parent_menu_id" />
```

Comment: Thank you. You are absolutely right. However, I need this new purchase order form to work only for a specific menu item. Normal Purchase Order Menu items and its PO forms should not be disturbed because of this. Any help would be appreciated. 
As of now, If I change the priority, its applied for all the PO menu items.